# The data structure that is the result of stack-based flattening of nested homogeneous forward iterators (vectors/arrays/lists)

Tags: data-structures, stack, computer-science

Let's say we have an array of vectors A: Vec[M] such that len(A[0]) = 5, len(A[1]) = 2, and len(A[2]) = 4.

[image]

One can traverse the stack that corresponds to A from left to write. One can also see that in order to adjust the data structure for higher dimensions, it is sufficient to have more integers in the beginning. How would you call such a data structure that is generic over the dimension and the type of stored elements?

Comment: It's a preorder traversal.  I wouldn't call it a data structure.

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a very efficient way to store things - adding or removing elements from those lists would require expensive shuffling of the other items. You also don’t have good random access of the individual items. Is there a particular use case you’re applying this to?

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm sequentially parsing Rust source files with syn library to find functions that are meant to be exported to other languages. Every source file can have arbitrary number of such functions and I will need only to generate the data structure and read it, i.e. there is no need to modify it.

Comment: It may seem inefficient but cache locality makes wonders. Insertion sort is the fastest algorithms for small inputs.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That makes a lot of sense. I don’t believe this layout has a name. There are a number of ways of laying out discrete “packets” into a single data stream, and only a few of them, to the best of my knowledge, have formal names. Maybe you can name this one after yourself? :-)

Comment: It seems like it can be called a nested VLA (variable-length array) https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html#variable-length-arrays

Comment: But if it needs to be stored on heap, its behavior will change https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48055#issuecomment-1000605480

Comment: Optimization trick: if the VLAs can grow in known limits, their ends can be filled with zeroes.